# Получение результата вызова SQL процедуры в PHP с помощью mysqli_prepare-bind-execute

Tags: php, mysqli

Не могу найти как можно получить результат вызова процедуры через mysqli_prepare.
Например если делать через mysqli_query -

```
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'login', 'password', 'db');
    $sql = 'CALL procedure_name(1, 2)';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        var_dump($row);
}
```

В данном случае я получаю результат вызова функции.
Если я делаю с помощью mysqli_prepare.

```
$sql = 'Call procedure_name(?, ?)';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
$p1 = 1;
$p2 = 2;
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $p1, $p2);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

То хотелось бы получить результат с помощью - mysqli_stmt_get_result(но он работает только на SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).

Единственное что я смог получить, это объект с помощью -

```
 $result = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
 $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
```

object(stdClass)[4] public 'name' => string 'rt' (length=2) public 'orgname' => string 'rt' (length=2) public 'table' => string 'i' (length=1) public 'def' => string '' (length=0)... И т.д.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить результат вызова функции с помощью mysqli_prepare?

Comment: Так же с помощью fetch как и в первом случае. Процедуры же никакого результата не возвращают. Выборка, происходящая в процедуре - это не результат выполнения.

Comment: @Mike Т.е. например $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
И его уже фетчить?
Но я пробовал фетчить $result и $field, вообще ничего не возвращает.

Answer (score 1):

Примеры PHP кода для вызова процедуры есть [в документации MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.html)

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("CALL p()"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

do {
    if ($res = $stmt->get_result()) {
        printf("---\n");
        var_dump(mysqli_fetch_all($res));
        mysqli_free_result($res);
    } else {
        if ($stmt->errno) {
            echo "Store failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
} while ($stmt->more_results() && $stmt->next_result());
```

То есть вам необходимо с помощью метода [`get_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) получить обычный `mysqli_result`, обработать его как обычно, освободить его, и затем так же обойти остальные результаты процедуры, если они есть. Это необходимо, так как в mysql процедура может вернуть несколько разных результатов, например упомянутая в мануале:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p() READS SQL DATA BEGIN SELECT id FROM test; SELECT id + 1 FROM test; END;
```

Содержит 2 результата

Comment: строго говоря, даже если процедура выдает 1 результат, все равно будет 2 результата. Ну то есть количество результатов всегда n+1. А невыбранный результат - это невозможность выполнять дальнейшие запросы.